# How to count point attributes that fall within a polygon in postgis?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

I have a point shapefile called pointA that has a field called fieldB, and a polygon file called polygonC, and I want to calculate the sum of fieldB for all the points that are within polygonC

How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load your shapefile(s) in as per instructions from http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/latest/dataadmin/pgGettingStarted/shp2pgsql.html

Then query using something like

```
SELECT sum(pointA.fieldB)
FROM pointA, polygonC
WHERE ST_Within(pointA.the_geom, polygonC.the_geom)
AND polygonC.id = ?
```

Comment: I think he intends to get all the points within the polygons, the last line ( second condition in where ) is optional, if I understood well what he wants

Comment: Hey @HichamZouarhi! Well I'm getting an error saying PolygonC does not exist when the table is clearly there. ERROR: relation "polygonC" does not exist

Comment: Hi there @Luffydude, one of the problems with postgresql is the name of tables with caps, that's why you'll have to change it to "polygonC"

Comment: The query worked now but nothing happened, the result box is completely empty

Comment: I tried it in my configuration and it worked, have you tried it without the last condition ( AND polygonC.id = ? ) ?

Comment: I found the problem, the coordinate systems needed to be the same. Thanks guys keep on rocking!